# How to specify default graphics device for X11 on ARM system?

Tags: x11, arm, gpu

I am running Parabola GNU/Linux (Arch variant) on an armv7 Chromebook. I am trying to get X11 to use the integrated Mali GPU; however, I am having difficulties.

`/dev/dri` lists two graphics cards: `card0` and `card1`. `card1` is the Mali GPU and `card0` I believe is a simpler fallback graphics device contained within the Rockchip Soc. When I start up X11, both devices seem to be recognized (as can be seen in the following log file); however it prints a message saying 'no primary bus or device found' and it appears to fall back to card0, which is the simpler device (not the Mali):

(showing a portion of my `/var/log/Xorg.1.log` file)

```
[  2710.485] (II) systemd-logind: took control of session /org/freedesktop/login1/session/_32
[  2710.487] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[  2710.488] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/dri/card0 226:0 fd 10 paused 0
[  2710.489] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card1)
[  2710.490] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/dri/card1 226:1 fd 11 paused 0
[  2710.491] (II) no primary bus or device found
[  2710.491]    falling back to /sys/devices/platform/display-subsystem/drm/card0
[  2710.491] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[  2710.491] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[  2710.495] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  2710.495]    compiled for 1.20.8, module version = 1.0.0
[  2710.495]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
```

I tried creating the following config file (`/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/30-driver-mali.conf`):

```
Section "Device"
      Identifier "Card1"
      Driver "panfrost"
EndSection
```

However, it didn't seem to help. As can be seen from the following log, X11 is still falling back to card0 and this time it fails to launch, because the panfrost driver is the wrong driver for that card:

```
[  2522.953] (II) systemd-logind: took control of session /org/freedesktop/login1/session/_32
[  2522.955] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[  2522.957] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/dri/card0 226:0 fd 10 paused 0
[  2522.958] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card1)
[  2522.959] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/dri/card1 226:1 fd 11 paused 0
[  2522.959] (II) no primary bus or device found
[  2522.960]    falling back to /sys/devices/platform/display-subsystem/drm/card0
[  2522.960] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[  2522.960] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[  2522.964] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  2522.964]    compiled for 1.20.8, module version = 1.0.0
[  2522.964]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
[  2522.964] (II) LoadModule: "panfrost"
[  2522.964] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module panfrost
[  2522.964] (EE) Failed to load module "panfrost" (module does not exist, 0)
```

So, how can I specify card1 to be the default graphics device for X11? It seems like I should be able to specify that somewhere, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: `LoadModule` in Xorg log refers to attempting to load a X server module from subdirectories of `/usr/lib/xorg/modules`. If I've understood correctly, it's expecting `/usr/lib/xorg/modules/libpanfrost.so`, or maybe `/usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/panfrost_drv.so`. but that file does not seem to exist. Try fixing that first.

Comment: @telcoM  thanks for your comment. There don't seem to be any xorg modules to do with panfrost in those folders and I'm not sure where I would get them. However, I have noticed the behavior seems to change when I upgrade mesa. I will edit my question shortly to provide more details.

Comment: @telcoM sorry, I haven't edited the question yet, but I think it's worth mentioning that I haven't got a specific xorg module installed for the 'card0' either, which it is defaulting to.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with ARM and its GPUs; but it seems to me that these GPU drivers depend pretty seriously on driver components in the kernel. Perhaps setting `Driver "panfrost"` is not the right thing to do at all? Perhaps you should use `modesetting` or `fbdev` instead, and the "panfrost" user-space components are only for the 3D acceleration/OpenGL libraries, which will pick the "panfrost" components automatically. Too bad there seems to be no easily-findable configuration examples...

Comment: @telcoM yes, `panfrost` is the kernel module for the Mali GPU, which is installed with Mesa. `rockchip_drm` is the kernel module for the fallback card0. The situation does seem a little confusing. I am going to re-write, as I'm not sure I'm asking quite the right question to get to the bottom of it. My issue might even be a bug in Mesa.